# Git stages changes that should be ignored by the .gitignore

Tags: git, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, bitbucket, gitignore

I've made a Unity Project and want to exclude some folders. I made the .gitignore look like this:

```
[Ll]ibrary/
[Tt]emp/
[Oo]bj/
[Bb]uild/
[Bb]uilds/
[Ll]ogs/
[Uu]ser[Ss]ettings/

# Visual Studio cache directory
.vs/

# Autogenerated VS/MD/Consuelo solution and project files
ExportedObj/
.consulo/
*.csproj
*.unityproj
*.sln
*.suo
*.tmp
*.user
*.userprefs
*.pidb
*.booproj
*.svd
*.pdb
*.mdb
*.opendb
*.VC.db
```

But some files in that folders are still being staged.

List of changes:

[image]

Comment: What does `git status` say about it? Btw, could you inline your image into text so it won't get deleted?

Answer (score 1):

If the file has been committed perviously, you will have to remove it from the index by running `git rm --cached fileName` , for full directories it would be `git rm -rf folderName`

Answer (score 0):

Few options:

1. Have you added/committed those files before?

- Git starts to track files once you **adding them to the staging area**
- In order to verify that the files are new and not tracked already check: `git status`, you mentioned that the files already in your staging area, so you need to check the status of the files.
- If you added the files git will track them from this point on and form this point on **they will be tracked even if you add them to `.gitignore`**

if the files are new they should be marked as New

[image]

---

## `.gitignore.io`

- I'm recommending using the `.gitignore.io` service to produce the `.gitignore`.

---

### How to "untrack" added files:

- If the files are already tracked in git you will need to remove them from the staging area and if they are committed so from the repository as well.

#### How to remove files in Git?

```sh
Remove the desired file/folder from the staging area (and leave them in the working directory)
git rm --cached <path
```

[image]

---

## Removing files from the repository

- If you already committed and pushed the code, you will need to "remove" those files from the history as well. If you will not remove them

You can use `git filter-branch` or BFG.
https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

> ###`BFG Repo-Cleaner`
> an alternative to git-filter-branch.

> The BFG is a simpler, faster alternative to git-filter-branch for cleansing **bad data** out of your Git repository history:

#### Examples (from the official site)

> In all these examples bfg is an alias for java -jar bfg.jar.

```
# Delete all files named 'id_rsa' or 'id_dsa' :
bfg --delete-files id_{dsa,rsa}  my-repo.git
```

[image]